# PHP search with multiple fields

Tags: php, mysql, search

I want to search data using ajax method with multiple fields search option (e.g. name, college, department, year, nationality e.t.c ). I have insert name for searching and rest of fields are empty than it went to foreach loop but this if (isset($_GET[$field]) && !empty($_GET['$field'])) condition not successful and went to else loop

```
  $fields = array(
  'name' => TRUE,
  'gender' => TRUE,
  'colf' => TRUE,
  'deptf' => TRUE,
  'natf' => TRUE,
  'fstatusf' => TRUE,
  'fyearf' => TRUE
  );
 foreach ($fields as $field => $like) {
  if (isset($_GET[$field]) && !empty($_GET['$field'])) {
    $value = $_GET[$field];
    $search[] = $field . ( $like ? ('LIKE "%' . $value . '%"') : ('="' . $value . '"') );
       }
 } 
  if ($search) {
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM fmaf WHERE ' . implode(' or ' . $search);
  }

else{
$sql="SELECT * FROM fmaf";

    }
```

Comment: pass only those input fields which have been provided by user

Comment: Please please please, **don't forget to validate/sanitize user input** (eg. `$_GET`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At last i have found the solution and thanks to cFreed and other who help me. My main concern is that if user want to search with one field only or more than 1 field in that case below answer is helpful for me and may be also for someone:

```
if (empty($_GET['name']) && empty($_GET['gender']) && empty($_GET['colf']) && empty($_GET['deptf']) && empty($_GET['natf']) && empty($_GET['fstatusf']) && empty($_GET['fyearf']))
{
    $sql="select * from fmaf ";
}
else
{
 $wheres = array();

$sql = "select * from fmaf where ";

if (isset($_GET['name']) and !empty($_GET['name']))
{
    $wheres[] = "name like '%{$_GET['name']}%' ";
} 

if (isset($_GET['gender']) and !empty($_GET['gender']))
{
    $wheres[] = "gender = '{$_GET['gender']}'";
} 

if (isset($_GET['colf']) and !empty($_GET['colf']))
{
    $wheres[] = "college = '{$_GET['colf']}' ";
} 

if (isset($_GET['deptf']) and !empty($_GET['deptf']))
{
    $wheres[] = "department = '{$_GET['deptf']}' ";
} 

if (isset($_GET['natf']) and !empty($_GET['natf']))
{
    $wheres[] = "nationality = '{$_GET['natf']}' ";
} 

if (isset($_GET['fstatusf']) and !empty($_GET['fstatusf']))
{
    $wheres[] = "finalstatus = '{$_GET['fstatusf']}' ";
}

if (isset($_GET['fyearf']) and !empty($_GET['fyearf']))
{
    $wheres[] = "fyear = '{$_GET['fyearf']}' ";
} 

foreach ( $wheres as $where ) 
{
$sql .= $where . ' AND ';   //  you may want to make this an OR
  }
 $sql=rtrim($sql, "AND "); 

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the query depending on the request. 
A toy example is this:

```
$sql = "select * from student where 1 = 1".(isset($name)?" AND name like '%$name%":"").(isset($country)?" AND country = '$country'":"").";";
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use a simple way, being able to face any case, like this:

```
// define searchable fields, with option for LIKE|EQUAL (TRUE|FALSE)
$fields = [
  'name' => TRUE,
  'country' => TRUE,
  'address' => TRUE,
  'gender' => FALSE,
  'state' => FALSE
];
foreach ($fields as $field => $like) {
  if (isset($_GET[$field]) AND !empty($_GET['$field'])) {
    $value = $_GET[$field];
    // prepare WHERE condition item, depending on LIKE option
    $search[] = $field . (
      $like ? ('LIKE "%' . $value . '%"') : ('="' . $value . '"')
    );
  }
}
if ($search) {
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM student WHERE ' . implode(' AND ' . $search);
}
```

Comment: I tried it but getting error and please see above i have updated my question

Comment: @SalmanKarim. I may have a bug in the code I proposed (not tested), so please report **exactly** the error you get.

Comment: I don't understand: your updated question is quite different from the original one. So first my proposed solution should be change accordingly. Then anyway you don't explain which error you get, nor with my code, nor with your new question...

Comment: 1st time all data have loaded but when i want to search data with selection than no data appear. I am not getting any error :(. I think have some logical issue with the if else statement. I have debug code and the values are passing in ajax jquery.

Comment: Apparently your current version is based on RiggsFolly answer, not mine: so first try adapating my own proposal. On the other hand, in your current version I notice that when field search params are all empty, your query shows that `status` is a distinct table, while the 2nd query doesn't take care of this.

Comment: I am getting error when i create fields as you mentioned but when i create field with array than i am not getting any error. Like operator just for name and rest of them we need to use = operator. I badly stuck in this issue. Please see above updated question

Comment: In your latest implementation you've changed `$fields` structrue from `array(field-name => like-option)` to `array(field-name)`. So it can't work at all because each step in `foreach ($fields as $field => $like)` populates `$field` with the item-no and `$like` with the field-name!